# How do I reference a Javascript routes file in my angularJS file on the client side in a node app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using require or import seems to disable the controllers in the angular file.

I need to access the results from a route and display part of those results to the view using angular binding, for example I want to put the username from the authentication route response on the front page in this single page application.

```js
// var users = require('.../controllers/users');
// import users from ...controllers/users.js

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('UserController', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "John Doe";
    $scope.userData = users;
});
```

My angular app.js is in the static directory and all others(models, routes...) exist in other directories in the root node app.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a REST Api as backend. So simply you can call the users GET Api from the controller. Something like this.

```
$http.get('/api/users/4').then(function(response) { $scope.userData = response.data };
```